# Picking One Random Result From Each Date

Tags: mysql, date, random

I have a db structured like this:

```
int, date, varchar
1, 2021-07-25, aaaa
2, 2021-07-25, aaba
3, 2021-07-25, aabb
4, 2021-07-26, bbbb
5, 2021-07-26, bbba
6, 2021-07-26, bbaa
7, 2021-07-26, babb
```

I need to pull one result for each date at random. So one result for 07-25 and one result from 07-26 with this example.

Sample Output:

> aaaa
> bbbb

Comment: FWIW, if 'randomness' is important, then I don't really think the accepted answer does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP BY` statement to help you achieve that, the query will be something like this:

```
SELECT varchar FROM {table-name} GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Is it true that a `group by` can generate random result ??

Comment: Not necessarily randomly, it might group them based on the first row fetched.

Comment: Yeah, but it's exactly what I needed. I just needed one varchar for each date and this is working perfectly. `$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT date, varchar FROM table GROUP BY date DESC LIMIT 30");`

Comment: If you're using MariaDB, this query will work however if you're using MySQL v8+, the query is `incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`... but I guess you've turned off that setting anyway. I also don't believe that your column name is `varchar`, if it is, I don't believe that your query don't have it wrapped in backticks because [VARCHAR is a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-V) in both MySQL & MariaDB. The query will [return an error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=e914840b34cb6bd28fefe7bfadc190f7)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try

```
select varchar from table where date='2021-07-25'
order by rand() limit 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea which, at least, satisfies the brief...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ralph97;

CREATE TABLE ralph97
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,date DATE NOT NULL
,my_string CHAR(4) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ralph97 VALUES
(1,'2021-07-25','aaaa'),
(2,'2021-07-25','aaba'),
(3,'2021-07-25','aabb'),
(4,'2021-07-26','bbbb'),
(5,'2021-07-26','bbba'),
(6,'2021-07-26','bbaa'),
(7,'2021-07-26','babb');
```

...

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY RAND()) x FROM ralph97)
SELECT id, date, my_string FROM cte WHERE x = 1;
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | date       | my_string |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  3 | 2021-07-25 | aabb      |
|  6 | 2021-07-26 | bbaa      |
+----+------------+-----------+

WITH cte AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY RAND()) x FROM ralph97)
SELECT id, date, my_string FROM cte WHERE x = 1;
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | date       | my_string |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  2 | 2021-07-25 | aaba      |
|  4 | 2021-07-26 | bbbb      |
+----+------------+-----------+
```